# How to prevent loss of 'link' for embedded chartdata

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently receiving a '*Linked File Not Available*' error when trying to manually open datasets for embedded charts in Word after successfully updating these datasets via a VBA script. I am trying to build a project which will allow users to automatically update a series of embedded charts based on a user defined worksheet which is produced monthly.

In order to support this project, I've been trying to find a way in which I can update chart data in Word using VBA while avoiding the `ChartData.Activate` method (*eventually crashes the program due to the burden of successive open / close actions **[context: I have around 300 charts in the largest of these reports]***).

I've attempted to update the data using a direct call to the **ChartData.Workbook** and **ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow** both of which allow me to successfully update the data. Following the successful update however, I get the below error when trying to access the dataset manually and can no longer access it via the Macro:

[Linked File Not Available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtgiO.png)

I know I am probably missing something simple, or perhaps am approaching this in the wrong way by going through Word but wanted to throw it out there to see if anyone has a solution which could resolve / explain what's causing the loss of these 'links' to embedded datasets?

[Chart Screenshot (Front)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96Ik.png)

[Chart Screenshot (Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxdfr.png)

To try and streamline testing; I've created a stripped down version of the overall code which I've been using to try and troubleshoot:

```
Dim x As Integer 'Counter used to breakout of routine once 1 chart updated.

Dim strChartTitle As String
Dim objChart As InlineShape
Dim objTargetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim objTargetWorksheet As Worksheet

x = 0

For Each objChart In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

    strChartTitle = objChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

    If x = 1 Then

        Exit Sub

    ElseIf strChartTitle Like "EHR Transactions Summary (By Endpoint)*" Then

        'objChart.Chart.ChartData.Activate
        objChart.Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow

        Set objTargetWorkbook = objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook
        Set objTargetWorksheet = objTargetWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        objTargetWorksheet.Range("C1:D11").Copy objTargetWorksheet.Range("B1")
        objTargetWorksheet.Range("D1").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, objTargetWorksheet.Range("C1").Value)

        x = 1
        objTargetWorkbook.close

    End If

Next objChart
```

Comment: Thanks @slightlysnarky, that seems to have done it although hit into one issue. Seems Word would spin up an Excel subprocess for every instance of calling a new chart's workbook which eventually crashed the routine when run against a large enough report. Managed to get around it by adding a objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.close call once the dataset had been dealt with. Happy to say I've managed to get it through a complete cycle from start to finish and in good time thanks to the above with a slight tweak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Couldn't find a way to update data on a large number of charts using vba without utilising the `Chart.ChartData.Activate` or `Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow` commands which either caused crash due to CPU load on successive load / unload (former method) or broke links between the embedded charts and their datasheets (latter method).

**Solution:**

Solution was provided in part by @Slightly Snarky in comment to original question / problem post. Despite Microsoft's documentation, it is possible to update data within Chart workbooks without the need to call an activate command by referencing the workbook and worksheet directly.
Re-wrote script to utilise the new method and confirmed not only did this allow me to edit data; it was able to do so while avoiding the performance hit inherent in the repeated open / close events caused by the two above methods.

On testing; one problem did come up in that MS-Word would spin up a new Excel sub-process each time the code referenced a different chart without killing the previous sub-process. Given these reports have up to 300 charts, this inevitably caused the routine to crash once enough sub-processes had built up against the CPU.

To resolve this issue, I tweaked the code to include a ChartData.Workbook.Close command after each chart update completes which has helped keep CPU burden to a minimum and prevented crashes due to overloading with Excel sub-processes.

```
Dim strChartTitle As String
Dim objChart As InlineShape

For Each objChart In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

 strChartTitle = objChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

 If strChartTitle Like "EHR Transactions Summary (By Endpoint)*" Then

     With objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

        .Range("C1:D11").Copy objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1")
        .Range("D1").Value = objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D1").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1").Value)

    End With

    objChart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.close

End If

Next objChart
```

Comment: @slightlysnarky ~ Unfortunately not, I've removed the close commands and rerun the test with an instance of Excel open but it continues to create a new sub-process for each new chart touched by the loop (up to around 45 - 50 before it bogs the CPU on my machine).

Comment: @slightlysnarky ~ Thanks for the pointer, I do make use of the With within my actual code so don't know why it didn't occur to me to use it in the testing script..... Either way, I've updated the solution entry to use a With statement and will accept it as an answer once StackOverflow lets me (says I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer). Thanks for your help, really appreciated!