# Use Word Content Control Values for chart object in same Word doc

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word, contentcontrol

Using MS Word (in my case 2010 version), I have constructed a form with Content Control elements to be filled out by the user. Now I want certain entries (that I already gave titles to) be shown in a chart inside the same Word document (not in a separate Excel document).

This should be an automated process, so that if the user changes one of the Content Control entries, the chart updates itself automatically; I would also be OK if the user had to press a button in order to update the chart (but the user shouldn't have to click around a lot, since I must assume the user to have little skills.)

So I inserted an Excel chart object in my Word form document. I also wrote some VBA code inside this Excel object to read the Content Control values from the Word document as source for the chart. But I think what I really need is the VBA code to be in my Word document itself (for example to be executed upon click on a button by the user), yet I don't know how to address the Excel chart object and the cells within.

My VBA code inside the Excel object is:

```
Sub ChartDataAcquirer()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim DocName As String
Dim ccX As String
Dim ccY As String
Dim datapairs As Integer

'''''''''' Variables '''''''''
DocName = "wordform.docm"
ccX = "titleX"
ccY = "titleY"
datapairs = 5
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents(DocName)

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To datapairs

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) ' The first row contains headline, therefore i+1
    .Value = wdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccX & i).Item(1).Range.Text    ' The CC objects containing the x values have titles "titleX1", "titleX2" ..., therefore "ccX & i"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Value = CSng(wdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccX & i).Item(1).Range.Text) ' To transform text into numbers, if user filled the CC object with numbers (which he should do)
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2)
    .Value = wdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccY & i).Item(1).Range.Text
    On Error Resume Next
    .Value = CSng(wdDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccY & i).Item(1).Range.Text)
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

I guess I need a similar code that is placed in and operates from the Word form document itself, but that is where I am stuck...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062138/how-to-prevent-loss-of-link-for-embedded-chartdata/61068993#61068993 . You may need to to deal with charts in Shape objects as well as in InlineShape objects.

Answer (score 0):

The following is demo code that shows how to access an embedded Excel chart.

Note that the Name (`Shapes([indexValue])`) of your chart `Shape` is probably different than in this code. You'll need to check and change that assignment. Also, your chart may be an `InlineShape` rather than a `Shape`, so you may need to adjust that bit, as well.

This code checks whether the `Shape` is actually a chart. If it is, the `Chart` object is accessed as well as its data sheet. Via that, it's possible to get the actual workbook, the worksheets, even the Excel application if you should need it.

```
Sub EditChartData()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim shp As Word.Shape
    Dim cht As Word.Chart
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet, xlApp As Excel.Application

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set shp = doc.Shapes("MyChart")
    If shp.HasChart Then
        Set cht = shp.Chart
        cht.ChartData.Activate
        Set wb = cht.ChartData.Workbook
        Set xlApp = wb.Application
        Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(1, 2).Value2
    End If
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set cht = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```